# JavaFX Cell Spacing?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Here is my code for my game of life i am creating, I want to try to add spacing between the alive cells but can't figure it out.

Can somebody help to do this? or is it possible to make a grid in the background?

```
public class ClickFX extends Application 
{
    public LifeGrid lg;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    GraphicsContext gc;
    ClickData clickData;
    int squareSize;
    Stage primaryStage;
    Color colours[] = { Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN,
            Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK };

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        squareSize = 6;
        int x = 80, y = 80;
        clickData = new ClickData(x, y);
        lg = new LifeGrid(x,y,"seed.txt");

        VBox root = new VBox(8);
        HBox buttons = new HBox(5);

        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button ngButton = new Button("Next Gen");
        ngButton.setOnAction(new ngButtonHandler());
        ngButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Click to Start!\nKeep clicking to Evolve!"));

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
        clearButton.setOnAction(new clearButtonHandler());
        clearButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Click to Clear"));

        Button randomButton = new Button("Random Generate");
        randomButton.setOnAction(new randomButtonHandler());
        randomButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Click to create Random Generation"));

        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setOnAction(new closeButtonHandler());

        buttons.getChildren().addAll(ngButton, randomButton, clearButton, closeButton);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(x * squareSize, y * squareSize);
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new mouseClickHandler());
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        primaryStage.setTitle("Game Of Life");
        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, buttons);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));![enter image description here][1]
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        }        


    public void init() throws Exception
    {
        super.init();
        Parameters parameters = getParameters();

        Map<String, String> namedParameters = parameters.getNamed();

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : namedParameters.entrySet())
        {
            if("width".equals(entry.getKey()))
            {
                x = Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue());
            }
            else if("height".equals(entry.getKey()))
            {
                y = Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

The action for the buttons are created below.

```
class clearButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                clickData.clear();
                gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                gc.fillRect(0, 0, clickData.getX() * squareSize, clickData.getY()
                        * squareSize);
            }
        }

        class closeButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        }

        class randomButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
        {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                lg.RandomGeneration();
                drawNG();
            }
        }

        class ngButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
        {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                drawNG();
                lg.Run();
            }
        }
```

Here I draw onto the canvas the alive cells.

```
    public void drawNG()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<lg.CG.length; i++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<lg.CG[0].length; k++)
            {
                if(lg.CG[i][k] == 1)
                {
                    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    gc.fillRect(k*squareSize, i*squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);               
                }
                else
                {
                    gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    gc.fillRect(k*squareSize, i*squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change your `fillRect` method call to add an offset to the x and y co-ordinates.

Comment: @colti - Could you give an example of how? Ill be able to understand better

Comment: Right now the width, height, horizontal distance and vertical distance between each cell are all equal to squareSize. To pad the cells, you need the distance between them to be greater than the size.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`gc.fillRect(k*squareSize, i*squareSize, squareSize, squareSize)`

to...

`gc.fillRect(k*squareSize + offset, i*squareSize + offset, squareSize, squareSize)`

where `offset` is the distance you want between them.